# @media query to differentiate mobile from tablet

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile

For multiple years I've been using `min-device-width` or `max-device-width` to differentiate mobile from tablet. Mobile CSS moves the cascading navigation menu to the bottom of the page, and simplifies the styling for readability. Tablet CSS leaves the page styling alone, as the screen size is sufficient to not require simplification. I have only iOS devices to test with. It works, but both `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` are deprecated in CSS and I am trying to move to `@media` to continue serving different CSS to both devices.

Where I am falling down is finding a clean method of doing so. My hope was that I could use some query like `hover: none` or `pointer: coarse` to detect one platform vs. the other, but iPhone and iPad both show as no hover, coarse pointer. My second attempt was to couple these queries with screen width query, but that has been a mess. Apple documentation shows native portrait-mode screen widths for recent iOS devices to be 640 to 1125px width for iPhones, and 1536 to 2224px for iPads. However, querying width in JS on my phone comes up with numbers that seem to instead match the UIKit widths (320-414px). Using a CSS `@media (max-width: 450px)` should match a phone, but it doesn't - it seems that the CSS is reading the native resolution width but JS is reading the scaled width. To get an element to only show up on my own iPhone I need to set `max-width` to something like 999px, but if it's truly reporting native resolution this would fail on an iPhone Plus - my phone is on the lower end of the screen size.

This seems pretty ridiculous. Is there a better way to serve one set of CSS rules to a mobile and another to a tablet, without having to set 37 different potential screen shape entries or use deprecated elements? I really don't want to have to rewrite my CSS every time a new phone model is released, or resort to browser sniffing - the less scripting running on the backend just for basic page display the better.

Per request: My really simple test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Test</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var devpxratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    var devwidth = screen.width;
    document.getElementById('ratio').innerHTML = devpxratio;
    document.getElementById('wide').innerHTML = devwidth;
    };
</script>


<style type="text/css">

.mobile, .tablet, .desktop, .touch, .hover, .fine, .phone {
    display: none;
    }

@media (hover: none) {
    .mobile { /* show all mobile-specific content */
        display: block;
        }
    }

@media (pointer: coarse) {
    .touch { /* show touch-only content */
        display: block;
        }
    }

@media (hover: hover) {
    .hover { /* show hover-capable content */
        display: block;
        }
    }

@media (pointer: fine) {
    .fine { /* show fine pointer content */
        display: block;
        }
    }

@media (hover: none) and (max-width: 375px) {
    .phone { /* guessing at mobile vs tablet based on width */
        display: block;
        }
    }

@media (hover: none) and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .tablet { /* guessing at mobile vs tablet based on width */
        display: block;
        }
    }


@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
    .desktop { /* show stuff that would be visible on desktop */
        display: block;
        }
    }
</style>        
</head>
<body>

<p>Device pixel ratio: <span id="ratio"></span></p>

<p>Device width: <span id="wide"></span></p>

<p class="mobile">No hover detected</p>

<p class="touch">Coarse pointer detected</p>

<p class="hover">Hover detected</p>

<p class="fine">Fine pointer detected</p>

<p class="phone">This is likely a phone</p>

<p class="tablet">This is likely a tablet</p>

<p class="desktop">This is likely a desktop</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected outcome on my iPhone is:

```
Device pixel ratio: 2

Device width: 375

No hover detected

Coarse pointer detected

This is likely a phone.
```

Actual output is:

```
Device pixel ratio: 2

Device width: 375

No hover detected

Coarse pointer detected
```

I can't get it to output "likely a phone" unless my specified `max-width` is 980px or higher. None of the results seem to make any logical sense. Javascript check for screen width tells me 375px, which matches expected screen width for my phone (second generation iPhone SE, which uses same screen as iPhone 8). Apple documentation states native resolution of an iPhone SE is 750px with a UIKit width of 375pt. I cannot find any math whatsoever to tell me why the numbers come out as they do. 375pt should be 500px, not 375; there's no logic to why the calculated screen size doesn't match the screen size used by CSS in the test page, and I cannot make heads or tails out of why any of the screen size numbers can relate to a CSS width of not more than 980px, unless the scaling factor is being reported incorrectly - it shows as 2, but scaling of 2.6 would result in a 375px screen equating to 980px. Again, especially with manufacturer specs, determining the screen size break points should not be this difficult...

Comment: `display: flex;` ?

Comment: Could you please put a working snippet into your question which demonstrates the problem - then we can try it on various devices. I have not come across the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Usual practice for responsive design is to address just several groups of devices defined by max. viewport width, so you don't need to fiddle with every possible screen size individually. As an example you can start with these:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp

Anyway CSS `@media (max-width: 450px)` should definitely match the phone of 320-414px screen size (since 320 < 450)... Could you please show us some code where it does not work for you?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do - just use a simple set of queries to feed mobile, tablet, or desktop layout rules. I can differentiate mobile/tablet vs. desktop via `hover` or `pointer` rules, but I can't differentiate mobile vs. tablet based on screen width. Results are just not making sense.

Comment: I see your CSS and it is invalid. There is nothing like "hover: none" or "pointer: fine" in CSS. Also your media queries are not in correct syntax... What is even "@media (hover: hover)" suppose to mean?

Comment: Seriously? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover ... it's part of media queries level 4, it's been supported by every major browser for a long time now. My test file above validates as CSS level 3 via W3C CSS validation tool. The entire point of this question is that device-width is deprecated in current specs (media queries level 4).

Comment: Ouch sorry, you are right!! I have never seen that before. But looks cool! :) Anyway it seems only "device-width" and "max-device-width" are deprecated, while "width" and "max-width" are completely ok... So why not to use those? That is standard way how to handle responsive design...

Comment: The issue is that the numbers are not adding up. Width detected by Javascript does not match device width reported in CSS, and using manufacturer-provided widths is not working. My expectation is that a width reported in JS would be used in the CSS breakpoints but it is not working on my devices.

Comment: Yep. That is a common issue. Just use "window.innerWidth" for getting the correct viewport width matching CSS values.

Comment: And well I see there is already better way of doing so (in terms of performance) with "window.matchMedia"... For example something like: if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {}